# Game recording. Play on one device record on another

Tags: dota-2, recording, obs

I am trying to record a video while playing a game as simple as this. But it is not so simple as it sounds.

My PC configuration :

**CPU**: Intel® Core™ i5-6402P, 2.80GHz, Skylake, 6MB, Socket 1151

**Motherboard**: ASUS H110M-R/C/SI, Socket 1151, Bulk

**GPU**: Sapphire Radeon R9 390 NITRO TRI-X , 8GB, GDDR5, 512 bit

Note: I am also using a 21:9 Ultrawide monitor with 2560:1080 resolution.

Now I run a few tests with the OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) which is free and it appear to be verry laggy. While in gameplay all seems normal but afterwards when I watch the video lags appear after a few seconds from the beggining.

So I saw a guy who was using one PC for racording and another for gaming or whatever. Is this a good idea I have a laptop with a pretty decent CPU like i7 can I use it only for recording or I should just record lower rate videos.

What do you think guys? In my opinion my PC should handle the job but apparently it doesn't. Is my PC config not good for recording while playing or I am doing something wrong?

Does someone have experience with recording gameplay or similar?

Note2: I set video FPS to 48 not 60 (in OBS) and turned on VSYNC in the game and it is way better but still not getting the quallity I want.

Comment: Im not sure, but may be http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I will give it a try there also

Comment: how much RAM do you have?

Comment: 2x4 HyperX fury DDR4 2133Mhz

Comment: You can try another recording program, eg. Vokoscreen, Bandicam (both free) or Action! ($, doesn't lag *at all*)

Answer (score 1):

```
I run a few tests with the OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) which is free and it appear to be verry laggy. While in gameplay all seems normal but afterwards when I watch the video lags appear after a few seconds from the beggining.
```

That just means your settings are not right for your machine, OBS is not the kind of software you download and just start using without knowing what you're doing, you need to have basic knowledge about every setting and you need to know what's optimal for **your** case.

What bitrate are you using? What resolution? are you downscaling or are you streaming native resolution?

This said, using another a dual-pc combo is a great idea for streaming but you really shouldn't need one for recording also you do need a capture card to do that and they can get quite expensive.